# Test if someone is logged out on another device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise, warden

We are using Rails and Devise, and I want to test when a user changes his password, that they are logged out on every device, except for the device which he does the password change with.

Manually I would test it like that:

- Log in with browser A
- Log in with browser B
- Change password with A
- Click something with browser B and see that you are not logged in any more.

How to test this automatically?

Comment: Are you using minitest or rspec?

Comment: If you are using capybara you can [create different sessions](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session). With selenium you could open different browsers.

Comment: Using Rspec, thanks for the Capybara Doc!